# SQLITE - Delete nth row (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

So I have a ListView and a DatabaseHandler, and I want to delete a ListView item based on a long click. It should be deleted from the database too.

But when I delete the first item with ID 1, the new first item in the ListView will be the item with ID 2 in the DataBase.

```
ListView           Database
1                  1
2                  2
3                  3
```

after delete

```
ListView           Database
1                  2
2                  3
```

I thought of deleting the database entry according to the ListView ID.

```
delete from (select * from Student WHERE rownum = 2)
```

But it gives me an error...

How should I do this? Thanks!

Comment: After deletion, just reread your db and fill your ListView again, after clearing it.

Comment: Yeah sure, but if I want to delete for example the new first item in the listview?

Comment: Then store the id in an invisible TextView (gone), filled in the custom adapter

Comment: Which id? So when a user deletes ListView item 1 I'll delete Database item 1. All is fine. But then the user decides to delete the next item in the ListView, still number 1, because the items move up. But my code tries to delete Database id 1, but there's no database id 1.

Comment: You're basically saying that you have no way of tying a list row to your database row, correct?  You need to solve that, perhaps by returning the id from your database "get" functions and storing it in your list data model.  We don't know how your code is set up so we can't help you more than that.

Comment: How do you get the items into your list view? With an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)?

Comment: no, don't delete the ListView position, store the database row id per each row you show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the ( n+1 )th record by the following :

```
SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET n;
```

n is the index you're after starting with zero. So you can select the 2nd row by:

```
SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

You can also delete the second row by :

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
```